# Possible to bridge PS3 to use laptop and iPhone shared 3g connection

Tags: ps3, ios, windows-7

I am able to broadcast a wireless signal from my iPhone to my laptop using an ad-hoc network. Unfortunately, PS3 does not recognize ad-hoc networks so I am unable to use this wireless connection.

My initial attempt to connect was as follows:

Allow my Windows 7 laptop to connect to the internet using USB tether to my iPhone (with MyWi software). This works and does not use any wireless signal from my laptop itself. I then tried to bridge both the wireless and LAN connections to an ethernet connected PS3 but nothing seems to work. The connection to my PS3 comes in and out frequently as if it is trying to find an internet signal, fails, the disconnects.

Has anybody had luck with this in the past?

Comment: 3G connection for videogames? Ugh, you don't want that!

Comment: If you don't get any good answers here, you might also try superuser.com, they may know more than us.

Comment: @Steve On super user, this question will get mercilessly closed. See, there's the word "games" in it.

Comment: @badp - when you don't have internet in the home, what other options do you have? I actually got this to work (slightly) but I think the upload speed of 3g is the real killer. Down is fine but up ruins the experience.

Comment: I'd have to resort to LAN parties :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With iOS 4.3 you can setup a wireless hotspot with your iphone. Look for "Personal Hotspot" and activate it. The PS3 can then connect to the iPhone wich is the access point.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Tether the iPhone to the computer using USB. After a internet connection is established, enable [ICS](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Using-ICS-Internet-Connection-Sharing) (Internet Connection Sharing) and use a ethernet cable to connect it to the PS3.

However a 3G connection is **not** recommended for gaming as the speed may vary according to your signal strength and the traffic, compared to wired broadband which is much much reliable and faster.